# How to get return value from AJAX in requireJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, requirejs

I structured my code with requireJS.
In my init.js

```
require(["jquery", "user"], function($, user){
    console.log(user.isLogin());
});
```

In my user.js

```
define(["jquery"], function($){
    return{
        isLogin: function(){
             var status = 0;
             function callApi(){
                 return $.ajax({
                 type: "post",
                 url: urls.api_isLogin,
                 dataType: "json"
             }
             callApi().done(function(data){
                 status = data.data;
                 console.log(status);
                 return status;
             });    
       }
    };
});
```

I can get the data from ajax call:

```
console.log(status);
//output: true
//means I can get the value from the ajax call
```

But how can I pass it into init.js?
I got "undefined" from:

```
console.log(user.isLogin());
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: I am asking how to implement this with requireJS, please read carefully.

Answer (score 0):

OK. I figured out by myself.

```
define(["jquery"], function($){
    return{
        isLogin: function(){
                 return $.ajax({
                 type: "post",
                 url: urls.api_isLogin,
                 dataType: "json"
             }    
       }
    };
});
```

Then in another file:

```
$.when(user.isLogin()).then(function(data){
    console.log(data.data);
});
```